# Read data from device via iPhone app

Tags: ios, iphone, usb, communication

I looked around for an answer but couldn't find anything related. My question is if I can connect another device with the iPhone/iPod/iPad via USB. Maybe I would need another device to connect the two, because I don't think this would work out of the box.

I want to write an app which can read out things like the temperature, humidity and other collected data from a device my company developed. You can read it out only by connecting it to the computer at the moment. Also it needs a special driver. I can access the driver's code and every thing else. So my question is if it would be possible to develop such an app and how. Do I have to build another connector or would it work if I connected the device and the iPhone directly via USB.

Another thought is, would it work over a Bluetooth connection? In the future my company has plans to build Bluetooth into their device to make it easier to communicate with other devices.

Comment: I'm not sure about how to do it via USB but have  you looked into this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CoreBluetooth_Framework/_index.html

Comment: So as I can see this Bluetooth would be an option, but I also read that the used Bluetooth device has to be in the "MFi" program. More about this here: https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/ I am going to read it tomorrow as it is already late here.